# Counter Doesn't Start from Set Value

Tags: counters

I have created the following counters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{CounterOne}

\newcounter{CounterTwo}[CounterOne]

\setcounter{CounterTwo}{1}

\newcommand{\One}{\stepcounter{CounterOne}{\textbf{\theCounterOne.\theCounterTwo}}}

\newcommand{\Two}{\stepcounter{CounterTwo}{\textbf{\theCounterOne.\theCounterTwo}}}

\begin{document}

\One

\One

\Two

\Two

\end{document}
```

Everything works fine except that the second counter doesn't start from 1 as I have set. Why is that? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't understand the meaning of `\newcounter` then. It has the following interface (see [`source2e`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf), section **21.1 Environment Counter Macros**, p 133):

> `\newcounter{<newctr>}[<oldctr>]`
>   Defines `<newctr>` to be a counter, which is reset when counter `<oldctr>` is stepped.

The important part here is that `<newctr>` is *reset* when `<oldctr>` is *stepped*. Just remove the optional `<oldctr>`:

> **1.1**
>   **2.1**
>   **2.2**
>   **2.3**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{CounterOne}

\newcounter{CounterTwo}%[CounterOne]

\setcounter{CounterTwo}{1}

\newcommand{\One}{\stepcounter{CounterOne}{\textbf{\theCounterOne.\theCounterTwo}}}

\newcommand{\Two}{\stepcounter{CounterTwo}{\textbf{\theCounterOne.\theCounterTwo}}}

\begin{document}

\One

\One

\Two

\Two

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `\setcounter` is just placed wrong. It should be in your `\One` after the `\stepcounter` for CounterOne, because you need to set it at every reset of your first counter (TeX starts at 0).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{CounterOne}

\newcounter{CounterTwo}[CounterOne]


\newcommand{\One}{\stepcounter{CounterOne}\setcounter{CounterTwo}{1}{\textbf{\theCounterOne.\theCounterTwo}}}

\newcommand{\Two}{\stepcounter{CounterTwo}{\textbf{\theCounterOne.\theCounterTwo}}}

\begin{document}

\One

\One

\Two

\Two

\end{document}
```